# Azure App Service Certificate for Azure VM

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine, azure-appservice, custom-domain

I have an SSL certificate which is used for a SQL Server VM. Auto-renewal is enabled, and this year the domain ownership verification is required. (last year was auto-renewed without needing any verification due to the fact it was still in the 395 days period)

I've followed the instructions for a Manual verification with Html Web Page Method, however it has been days and the status is still 'Pending Issuance'.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The instruction email that I've received upon requesting the 'Email Instructions':
[image]

In the email there is a link at the end which needs to be clicked when the updates are made and domain is ready to be verified. Upon opening the link, I receive the following screen:
[image]

Can someone help me with this, or there are others who had the same issue and got a workaround? Thank you!

Comment: I think there's a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72109869/pending-issuance-azure-ssl-app-service-certificate?rq=2, I hope it helps